# What does "It" in "It'll put" refer to?

Tags: meaning

In heist-comedy movie *Logan Lucky (2017)*, nurse said to Joe Bang, who was admitted to infirmary from
prison because of nausea:

> Nurse: A lot of you guys coming in here like that. It's that business
> with the water. Say you can't  drink it but it's okay to shower in it.
> I don't know about all that. Hmm. More barf than we saw after that
> one Thanksgiving when everything had gone bad. **It**'ll put  a girl off
> of turkey forever.

What does "It" in "It'll put" refer to? Does it refer to water used for Turkey or is it refer to the Thanksgiving that caused all the barf?

Comment: From my own knowledge turkey is a dish generally served at Thanksgiving, therefore it in this case is most likely referring to the Thanksgiving incident. It is a bit of a non sequitur, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nurse would see a lot of turkey being barfed up. If she had planned to go home and celebrate Thanksgiving that evening, she would be put off by the idea of eating it.

In my opinion, "it" refers to seeing a lot of barfed up turkey.